# Identifying UriBuilder implementation used by Spring WebClient

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-reactive

I use the below syntax to make a get call using get client. In the below example , which implementation of URIBuilder is being used and how is automatically inferenced?

```
webclient.get().uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/api/person/{personId}")
    .queryParam("param1", aDouble)
    .queryParam("param2", "A string value with spaces")
    .queryParam("param3", aListOfValues)
    .queryParam("param4", null)
    .build(anInteger))
```

This is the webclient that I am using - [WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html#builder--)

Comment: what's the `webclient` that you're using?

Comment: @CostiCiudatu - I am using https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html#builder--

Comment: Hmmm... it should be either `UriComponentsBuilder` or `DefaultUriBuilder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decide which implementation is used [`WebClient`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html) by providing a [`UriBuilderFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriBuilderFactory.html) while building it.

The [`WebClient.Builder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.Builder.html) has a [`uriBuilderFactory(UriBuilderFactory)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.Builder.html#uriBuilderFactory-org.springframework.web.util.UriBuilderFactory-) method where you can provide your implementation.

If you don't provide one, it currently uses [`DefaultUriBuilderFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/DefaultUriBuilderFactory.html) which produces [`UriComponentsBuilder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html) instances.

---

<sub>You could always instrument your code to print `uriBuilder.getClass()` for confirmation.</sub>